# Simple Regression Example pyBrain

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, regression, pybrain

I am trying to make the simpliest regression on pyBrain but somehow I'm failing.

The Neural Network should learn the function Y=3*X

```
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet
from pybrain.structure import FullConnection, FeedForwardNetwork, TanhLayer, LinearLayer, BiasUnit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *

n = FeedForwardNetwork()
n.addInputModule(LinearLayer(1, name = 'in'))
n.addInputModule(BiasUnit(name = 'bias'))
n.addModule(TanhLayer(1,name = 'tan'))
n.addOutputModule(LinearLayer(1, name = 'out'))
n.addConnection(FullConnection(n['bias'], n['tan']))
n.addConnection(FullConnection(n['in'], n['tan']))
n.addConnection(FullConnection(n['tan'], n['out']))
n.sortModules()

# initialize the backprop trainer and train
t = BackpropTrainer(n, learningrate = 0.1, momentum = 0.0, verbose = True)

#DATASET
DS = SupervisedDataSet( 1, 1 )
X = random.rand(100,1)*100
Y = X*3+random.rand(100,1)*5
for r in xrange(X.shape[0]):
    DS.appendLinked((X[r]),(Y[r]))

t.trainOnDataset(DS, 200)
plt.plot(X,Y,'.b')
X=[[i] for i in arange(0,100,0.1)]
Y=map(n.activate,X)
plt.plot(X,Y,'-g')
```

It doesn't learn anything. I have tried to remove the hidden layer (because in this example we don't even need that) and the network started to predict NaNs.
What's going on?

EDIT: This is the code that solved my problem:

```
#DATASET
DS = SupervisedDataSet( 1, 1 )
X = random.rand(100,1)*100
Y = X*3+random.rand(100,1)*5
maxy = float(max(Y))
maxx = 100.0
for r in xrange(X.shape[0]):
    DS.appendLinked((X[r]/maxx),(Y[r]/maxy))

t.trainOnDataset(DS, 200)

plt.plot(X,Y,'.b')
X=[[i] for i in arange(0,100,0.1)]
Y=map(lambda x: n.activate(array(x)/maxx)*maxy,X)
plt.plot(X,Y,'-g')
```

Answer (score 4):

The basic pybrain neurons are going to output something between 0 and 1.  Divide your Y by 300 (the maximum possible value), and you'll get better results.

More generally, find the maximum Y for your dataset, and scale everything by that.

Comment: I also had to divide the input by it's maximum (100). When I start the training the neurons output values above 1 and below 0 .. i am not understanding how this works..

Comment: I haven't poked into the internals of pybrain to check how it works, but it is in any event a good general practice to scale your inputs, so that when you have multiple inputs (which, granted, you don't have here, but in other cases you will) they start off weighted about the same.